# .NET Lambda package command fails after upgrade to Core 3.1

Tags: .net, .net-core, aws-lambda, gitlab

I just upgraded all of my projects from .NET Core 2.1 to 3.1. And before the upgrade, I would use a CI/CD script with GitLab to build and push the code to AWS.

But now, the **build** portion of the script is failing.

```
build:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - src/MyApp.Api/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get -y install zip
    - cd src/MyApp.Api
    - dotnet restore
    - dotnet build -c Release
    - export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
    - dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
    - dotnet lambda package -c Release --framework netcoreapp3.1
```

When this gets pushed to GitLab, I get the following error:

```
$ dotnet lambda package -c Release --framework netcoreapp3.1
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.1.13 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I have checked and double-checked all of my Project Settings, and they're all set to `dotnetapp3.1` or `netstandard2.0`. I have no idea what is using `'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0'`

I also have the following in `MyApp.App.csproj` file.

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Tools" Version="2.1.3" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have the `DotNetCliToolReference` in your project file. That was used back in the day before the .NET CLI had the concept of tools. Now your command `dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools` takes care of making the tool available.

I think what is happening is even though you ran the `dotnet tool install` command which installed version 5.1.0 of the tool your `DotNetCliToolReference` is forcing the old 2.1.3 version to be used which was built for .NET Core 2.0.